# Return "values" as a type from combined values

Tags: typescript, types

I have a helper which concatenates enums to return a nested "enum"

```
export type CombineEnums<P, C> = {
  [KP in keyof P]: {
    [KC in keyof C]: KP extends string ? KC extends string ? `${KP}${KC}` : never : never;
  };
};

export enum RequestTypes {
  Request,
  Success,
  Failure,
}

export function createActions <P>(actionTypes: P, requestTypes: any = RequestTypes): [CombineEnums<P, any>, string[]] {
  const actions = Object.keys(actionTypes).reduce((acc, actionKey) => ({
    ...acc,
    [actionKey]: Object.keys(requestTypes).reduce((reqAcc, reqKey) => ({
      ...reqAcc,
      [reqKey]: `${actionKey}${reqKey}`
    }), {})
  }), {}) as any;
  const KeyToVal = _.flattenDeep(actions);
  type Keys = keyof typeof KeyToVal;
  type ValuesTypes = typeof KeyToVal[Keys];
  return [actions, ValuesTypes]
}
```

I want to be able to use this like so:

```
enum Actions = {
    Open,
    Close

}
const [actions, types] = createActions(Actions);
// the actions are working, eg:
// actions.Open.Request = 'OpenRequest'
// actions.Open.Success = 'OpenSuccess' 
// actions.Open.Failure = 'OpenFailure' 
// actions.Close.Request = 'CloseRequest'
// actions.Close.Success = 'CloseSuccess'
// actions.Close.Failure = 'CloseFailure'
```

However i can't get the "types" to work, I'd like "types" to basically equal this

```
// types = 'OpenRequest' | 'OpenSuccess'  | 'OpenFailure'  | 'CloseRequest' | 'CloseSuccess' | 'CloseFailure'
```

However what i've tried clearly isn't working!

EDIT:
Getting the following error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '("OpenRequest" | "OpenSuccess" | "OpenFailure" | "CloseRequest" | "CloseSuccess" | "CloseFailure" | "UpdateRequest" | "UpdateSuccess" | "UpdateFailure")[]'
```

When trying to use like so:

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQIJ5TEgwjAtgIwEsA7MAUWIFdcBnAHgAUAabAPiQF4kBvUJfpAG0A0gyQkkAazCoYAMyQMAugC4efAZpFZxxKTPnZVSUUkgIwxACY0kNBHBIBzJAH4TO85Zt2Hzt0gABgAk3KIAvqHCWOGBSGqkAG5gcPFISSkA3Br84dkgeaBF4NDwyGgYSABiADYAhggWxDgEJORUtIwsWOxcvCBaphLSsgrKav2agzrDBgpYxqZe1rb2jsQu7tFmEE0+a-7uIWEMkWExcQlgyalXN-ma4YIjhgv5Ty9jSvmgkLCIZg6SAASmAAI6UMD2AAq6Ch6gGAlBEKhCCYOSQAGVKABjHFQmjoxH8Kp1Qg1ShwMBE8LFYpWMA4+pUpBySjEHEIQgwPQ4qkNMAAQU53OI9AYrAAFHURTzYRgaGoGABKNSCFpEUgUajilgVMCGZGQmFwmisImaSUHDZIABk1XqjUsGra2s6zBQcMN4ONCHlUNYysESm+xUs1CQwq5PNskwEAHkMMQLQIsDUYDQwKBaSBQDiY8hBDLo2K9aalJwkHywAKo6KaJK6zHlfli-WAHRpjNgduk8mUrMgAD0Q5QAAtMG2Y0g6iyAO7wSTOFhgJwqUAjmeysXtxOWdtG1GVgDke+Ih-sx43o6nO7P7exeIJJ7Pj-xNBoV+HN+3NF3Sd7MkKRZLhTyTPtgLAL9N1vP8u0zA8fSPUD4LAC8EGgn8Szg9MELfZ8UNwsB8I-TCt2wzsiMA-sQKQY9UIggcvzDUoARICw4DkGVMAAIUoKwnDABAmz0ON9TUfVDH1Gh3hY-5kHzMVkBgJM+IEoTK0lVUkDUwThO3Th2ElMS4TUWD-33dCaRbIA)

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqQ7Qm) work for you?  The implementation of `createActions` is distracting me here, since it seems to depend on lodash and you're returning a type as a value.  If the implementation doesn't matter, maybe it should be replaced with a declaration (like I did in my link above) in an [edit].  If it does matter, can you edit it to be a [mre] of your issue without external dependencies?

Comment: Wow this is much simpler than what i had!

I've implemented what you've provided, however I've updated my Question with an error I'm having trying to use "types" @jcalz

Comment: Added a reproducible playground for you @jcalz

Comment: Why do you want to assign an enum value to a variable of type "array of enum values"? Your code works when you remove `[]` from the `createActions` definition

Comment: Thankyou @GuerricP This works perfect

Comment: Why do i get this error when importing the declared function to a .ts file? `(0 , _actions_utils__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createActions) is not a function or its return value is not iterable`

Comment: Wait, do you want `types` to be a union of string literals or an *array* of those? You originally had `string[]`, so I was imagining `("OpenRequest"|...|"CloseFailure")[]`, an array type. Can you clear that up? Assuming you want an array, then `typeof types[number]` is what you want instead of `typeof types`, like [this](//tsplay.dev/w2EY4W). Do you want me to write that up as an answer?

Comment: Your followup question bout getting a runtime import error seems to be out of scope of the question as originally asked and is dependent on the implementation of `createActions` and whatever module stuff is happening in your environment, and has nothing to do with the static types which are, after all, erased upon transpilation to JS.    I'd suggest that such a question should get its own separate post.